# How to modify the JITSI flutter plugin and import the modified package?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-layout

I am currently working on the JITSI-meet plugin in flutter. Right now I want to add more button inside the Video screen and want to edit the existing screen. I have currently forked the repo and modified the screen. Current Jitsi plugin uses the flutter channel so I have modified the activity file but I don't know how to repackage files again and import into the flutter project. Any help or pointers are welcomed.

Comment: Have you seen: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin and https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/write-flutter-plugin#0